# How do I send special unicode characters in AutoHotkey?

Tags: special-characters, autohotkey

I have a fairly simple script that is not sending special Polish characters.

**The script:**

```
<^>!e::SendInput {Raw}asdęasd
```

I expected to get `asdęasd` every time I pressed <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, but instead what I get is `asdasd`. The `ę` letter is left out.

I have AutoHotkey x64 Unicode version installed. The script is also saved in Unicode. Should I use UTF-8?

Comment: For testing it, save the code in UTF-8  as UTF-8 test.ahk and run it. ANSI is the system default setting.

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Save file as **UTF-8 with BOM**.

- In Sublime Text: `File` > `Save with Encoding` > `UTF-8 with BOM`.
- In Notepad++: `Encoding` > `UTF-8 BOM`

Works with the script:

```
<^>!e::SendInput {Raw}asdęasd
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me finally was to trick it like so:

```
<^>!e::
SendInput 119
SendInput {Shift down}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Shift up}{Alt down}{x}{Alt up}{Right}
Return
```

Where `119` is `ę`'s Unicode code.

Comment: How did you figure this out? I'm confused why this combination of shift, alt, and arrow keys would print a unicode character.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I suspect that line is incidental to another program the OP is using.